What script should be run before every deploy? in firebase setting up GitHub Action deploys in React Vite application
We are trying to host our React-Vite Application using Google Firebase and after deploying the application we are trying to set up the CI CD actions in GitHub. After running these commands in the terminal
? Set up the workflow to run a build script before every deploy? Yes
? What script should be run before every deploy? npm ci && npm run build
Our deployment fails in GitHub. We used to run the application locally using npm run dev
Is there different build script we should give before deploy?????
I tried giving npm run build as script , vite build and npm run dev all failed

Can you please provide details on how you configured your Github workflows? It would help a lot
